# SharePoint Framework (SPFx) -- Web Part Solution Uploaded, Enabled, Not Deploying

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, web-parts, spfx, sharepointframework

I'm trying to deploy a custom web part solution built with SPFx to my site collection app catalog on SharePoint. When I upload the .sppkg file, I get no errors, and the web part is automatically 'enabled'. According to [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page), I should at this point be prompted to deploy the web part. But I'm not getting that prompt and I can't find any option to actually deploy the thing.

Here is what my app catalog looks like post-upload:
[app catalog view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzLns.png)

This problem also happens when I try to upload/deploy the default SPFx project generated by the yeoman generator (@yo/sharepoint). This leads me to believe it's an issue with my app catalog rather than my code.

I'm using the following commands to bundle and package the solution:

```
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

I also tried without the --ship option, no help.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, I'm desperate at this point. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you click the "deploy" button? https://i2.paste.pics/5b2738c3d92e74d1abcf8985443de471.png